# Need Suggestion : react-admin <DateField> date parse issue

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-admin

I want to change millisecond Unix time (1642417268) into readable format. Code is as follows

```
    <DateField 
     source={latest_event_time}
      options={{ weekday: 'long', year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric' }}
      label="TIME"
      />
```

// result should be 17/01/2022, 16:31:08. but getting Tuesday, 20 January 1970.

How to fix it.

Note : code is working in

```
<FunctionField
          sortable
          label="Time"
          render={record => `${unixParser(record.latest_event_time)}`}
 />
```

but for DateField not working. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

The error is because your timestamp **is in seconds, not milliseconds**.

Indeed, internaly the DateField does a:

```
const date = value instanceof Date ? value : new Date(value);
```

and `new Date();` expects a timestamp in milliseconds.

If you really want a working DateField, either use a FunctionField (as you proposed), change your timestamp to milliseconds, or copy/paste the code of `/node_modules/ra-ui-materialui/src/field/DateField.tsx` do do your own component with a *1000.